# python - listing animals and which animal beats who by alphabetical order

Tags: python

so I have a activity in which I need to commentate a animal contest, the winner will depend on the animal name, the animal with the first letter in the alphabet will win. eg if there was a bee, cat and a dog the bee would beat the cat and dog, and the cat will beat the dog. So my code so far is,

```
  animal_name = input("Animal Name: ")
  animal = []
  while animal_name != "":
      animal.append(animal_name)
      animal_name = input("Animal name: ")
  animal.sort()
```

so far i have put my input and I have separated them so that they are alphabetical. What the code is meant to output is,

```
Animal Name: Bee
Animal Name: kangaroo
Animal Name: Pig
Animal Name: 
Bee beats Kangaroo
Bee beats pig
Kangaroo beats Pig
```

I am having difficulties because I'm not sure what steps to take also the number of animals can change.

There will be 2 or more animals, the animals name will be entered in proper case (starts with upper case and ends with lower case) and the animal name won't be repeated

Thank You.

Comment: What about the comparison between upper and lower letters ? will this matter ? because `A` > `a`

Comment: @Cajuu' sorry, I just edited the post so the user will enter the animal name starting with a upper case and the rest with lower case, thank you

Comment: If you want to have as many animals as you want, just: `number_of_animals = input("How many animals are in the contest: ")` and in the condition of while put something like: `while len(animal) < int(number_of_animals)`

Answer (score 2):

If you have your list already sorted (`animal.sort()`) then just loop and print.

```
for index, a in enumerate(animal):
    for b in animal[index+1:]:
        print '{0} beats {1}'.format(a, b)
```

Comment: hey, thank you for helping,I was wondering though I wouldn't know how many animals there would be and I have to say who beats who so would I have to print it several times?

Comment: Here we are traversing the whole list of animals `for index, a in enumerate(animal):`, so it does not matter how many animals will be there, all will be considered and printed.

Answer (score 1):

## With Itertools

You can do this with itertools. It's not the fastest solution because filter have to loop over the permutations to remove some value. You can use list comprehension here, too.

```
import itertools

animalList = ["dog", "cat", "bee"]
animalList.sort()
perm = filter(lambda (x,y): x is not y and x < y, itertools.product(animalList,animalList))
for x,y in perm:
    print('{0} beats {1}'.format(x, y))
```

**Output**

```
bee beats cat
bee beats dog
cat beats dog
```

## Hack solution with itertools and python 3.x

For python 3.x you can make a hacky solution in 2 lines (I tested with python 3.5). If the list is sorted you have a one-liner.

```
import itertools

animalList = ["dog", "cat", "bee"]
animalList.sort()
[(1,print('{0} beats {1}'.format(x, y)))[0] for x,y in itertools.product(animalList,animalList) if x is not y and x < y ]
```

**Output**

```
bee beats cat
bee beats dog
cat beats dog
```

Comment: i've added a +1, but notice that a list comprehension should not be used for side effects like printing, you are building a list for that wich will be in memory....

Comment: @DanielSanchez You are completely right. Cause of this I called it "hacky solution". Think it is an unpythonic way to do this.

Comment: yeah, I understood that, thats why I still gave you +1 :), but is not good to show this to learning people.

Answer (score 0):

The full working code would be this:

```
number_of_animals = input("How many animals are in the contest: ")
animal = []
while len(animal) < int(number_of_animals):
    animal_name = input("Pokemon Name: ")
    if animal_name == " or animal_name in animal:":  # if animal is already in list or nothing is entered, continue
        continue
    animal.append(animal_name)
animal.sort()

for index, a in enumerate(animal):
    for b in animal[index+1:]:
        print('{0} beats {1}'.format(a, b))  # for python < 3 just use print '{0} beats {1}'.format(a, b)
```

P.S: I used @Muhammad Tahir answer as it does exactly what it's meant to.

Updated due to comments:

```
animal = []
animal_name = "placeholder"

while animal_name != "":
    animal_name = input("Pokemon Name: ")
    animal.append(animal_name)
    animal.sort()

del animal[0]  # remove blank input

for index, a in enumerate(animal):
    for b in animal[index+1:]:
        print('{0} beats {1}'.format(a, b))
```

**Output:**

```
Pokemon Name: you
Pokemon Name: him
Pokemon Name: me
Pokemon Name: 
him beats me
him beats you
me beats you
```

The second one it's just a fast solution. There can be improvements, of course.

Comment: hey thank you for helping, however in my code I don't need to know how many animals will be in the contest, the only output should be the animals and who beats who. Will this change how I type in my code?

Comment: the program should stop once the user doesn't enter anything and just presses enter, I have put an example of the output there should be one line where theres nothing and then the next line would say who beat who. Sorry if i'm being a little picky

Comment: @itz_mee I updated my answer. It's this what you want ?

Comment: @itz_mee Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the `.join()` method of a string, namely the new line character, in association of a syntactic construct named *generator expression* to build on the fly what you want to output, e.g.,

```
In [1]: l = ['ada', 'berenice', 'cheryl', 'diana']

In [2]: print('\n'.join(l[i]+' beats '+w for i in range(len(l)-1) for w in l[i+1:]))
ada beats berenice
ada beats cheryl
ada beats diana
berenice beats cheryl
berenice beats diana
cheryl beats diana

In [3]:
```

Let's focus on the generator expression, that is the argument of `'\n'.join()`

```
(l[i]+' beats '+w for i in range(len(l)-1) for w in l[i+1:])
```

it's just a chain of inline `for` loops, with the rightmost loop changing faster that produces an iterable, whose elements are, of course, `ada beats berenice` ... `cheryl beats diana`.

At this point you use `.join` to create a long string where those elements are joined by the newline character and the last step is to print this long string...

Note that I used Python3, so that I had to use parentheses around the argument of print, you are not required to do that.